# golang: Read multiline error response from smtp.SendMail

Tags: go

I am using this code:

```
err := smtp.SendMail(
    smtpHostPort,
    auth,
    sender,
    []string{recipient},
    []byte(message),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("sendSmtp: failure: %q", strings.Split(err.Error(), "\n"))
}
```

However the multiline error response seems truncated:

```
 2013/02/06 11:54:41 sendSmtp: failure: ["530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"]
```

How can I get the full multiline error response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records, this bug has been fixed:

https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5700